# Can anyone explain if condition from this algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, cloud

```
input: hostList, utilThreshold

hostList.sortDecreasingUtilization()
lastIndex = hostList.indexOfLastNonZeroHostUtilization()
for i := lastIndex downto 1
  for j := 1 to i - 1
    if hostList[j].currentUtil() + hostList[i].currentUtil() <= utilThreshold
      vmList = hostList[i].getAllVms()
      host[i].deleteAllVms()
      host[j].addVms(vmList)
      break
```

This pseudocode is from

> [Green Cloud Computing: Greedy Algorithms for Virtual Machines Migration and Consolidation to Optimize Energy Consumption in a Data Center](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=GcPhIf4AAAAJ&citation_for_view=GcPhIf4AAAAJ:u5HHmVD_uO8C)
>
> Rasoul Beik Islamic Azad University – Khomeinishahr Branch, Isfahan, Iran

some research paper. I read the paper, but they don't have any *explanation* of this algorithm.

This is the *description* from the paper:

> this algorithm is Minimum Host Utilization Selection, Maximum Host Utilization Allocation (MinMax_HU)
>
> In this algorithm hosts are periodically sorted based on their utilization; VMs in the less efficient hosts are moved to the more efficient hosts, provided that utilization of efficient host does not exceed utilization threshold defined in the algorithm.

Can anyone explain me this Algorithm line by line? I don't understand the if condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All it is doing is moving VMs onto hosts which have sufficient capacity to hold two hosts' current set of VMs, which will free up the resources required by one of the hosts.

Forget hosts and VMs: imagine you're moving house, and you've got too many cardboard boxes of books to fit in the van. Each cardboard box can hold some maximum number of books: you might be able to take all of the books out of one cardboard box and put them in another; then you will need fewer boxes overall.

So, the algorithm is basically:

```
for box1 in boxes:
  for box2 in (boxes without box1):
    if (# books in box1 + # books in box2) < (max # books in a box):
      move all books from box1 to box2
      throw away box1
```

There's some sorting stuff in there too, just to make try to make the algorithm utilize the available space well: it sorts by decreasing utilization (c.f. number of books in each box); the iteration order in the inner loop means that you will try to combine hosts (c.f. boxes) to leave the minimum remaining space afterwards.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a easy explanation with example :)